# How do you construct composite messages in rosjava?

Tags: rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recently, rosjava changed so that you can no longer create a message structure like so:

```
org.ros.message.std_msgs.String str = new org.ros.message.std_msgs.String();
str.data = "Hello world! " + sequenceNumber;
```

Instead it looks like the only way to create a message is by calling "newMessage()" on a publisher and then using accessor methods like so:

```
std_msgs.String str = publisher.newMessage();
str.setData("Hello world! " + sequenceNumber);
```

This makes it really hard to construct things like geometry_msgs/PoseArray messages, where you need to create a bunch of other message types to populate the message. Listing the symbols defined in "rosjava_messages-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" I don't see any instance fields or ways to create messages without an unclear series of factories.

[This diff shows the API change in use in the pubsub tutorial.](http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/source/diff?spec=svn1f8489dd1ed959cbbbe803894983c729686d3e80&r=7bb8828eab268cf553aab3ae14546c32404d66e5&format=side&path=/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/src/main/java/org/ros/tutorials/pubsub/Talker.java&old_path=/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/src/main/java/org/ros/tutorials/pubsub/Talker.java&old=966a534dd25246185fcfe1ba283c8870d920c596) (though it has changed a bit since then)

For the curious, the symbols defined for geometry_msgs.PoseArray are:

```
rosjava_messages-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar(geometry_msgs/PoseArray.class):
00000279 C geometry_msgs.PoseArray
00000008 D geometry_msgs.PoseArray._TYPE:Ljava/lang/String;
00000008 D geometry_msgs.PoseArray._DEFINITION:Ljava/lang/String;
         T geometry_msgs.PoseArray.getHeader:()Lstd_msgs/Header;
         T geometry_msgs.PoseArray.setHeader:(Lstd_msgs/Header;)V
         T geometry_msgs.PoseArray.getPoses:()Ljava/util/List;
         T geometry_msgs.PoseArray.setPoses:(Ljava/util/List;)V
```

And in this case, it's unclear to me how to construct geometry_msgs/Pose messages to populate the list of Poses in geometry_msgs/PoseArray.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31399/how-do-you-construct-composite-messages-in-rosjava?/) by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5809 on 2012-04-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can make `geometry_msgs/Pose` messages now using the `MessageFactory` that you can get from `Node::getTopicMessageFactory()`.  The MessageFactory takes a type that you can get through the interface like so:

```
geometry_msgs.Pose msg = mNode.getTopicMessageFactory().newFromType(geometry_msgs.Pose._TYPE);
```

At least that is how I am doing it on `438c2ba9b5ad`, and looking at the hg repository, it doesn't look like this method has changed since then.

---

Originally posted by [jamuraa](https://answers.ros.org/users/534/jamuraa/) with karma: 218 on 2012-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-04-09**:
That's what I was looking for, thanks!

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-04-10**:
I'm thinking about a way to make this a little easier for collections of messages. In general I'd like to avoid the necessity of using MessageFactory instances like that.